# How to set associated labels in custom HTML

Tags: html, css, wordpress, lighthouse

I am currently trying to fix a problem with my page speed scores using lighthouse. I keep getting an error "Form elements do not have associated labels" and it is specifically addressing one element on my website in particular and that is my mobile nav menu on the home page.

Here is my website https://verticalk9.com/

Here is the HTML that i placed inside the element:

```
<input class="lytbox-nav_control" id="nav-control" type="checkbox">
<label class="lytbox-button" for="nav-control">
  <div class="hamburguer">
    <span>
    </span>
    <span>
    </span>
    <span>
    </span>
  </div>
</label>
<div class="lytbox-navigation">
  [elementor-template id="1434"]
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't want to break my site as I don't have very much coding knowledge. This code was a copy paste from a suggestion for a more interactive nav menu button.

Comment: Please put your code through a validator. The HTML is not currently correct.

Comment: I put this code through a validator and it does show errors. But as i mentioned in my question, I am unfamiliar with code or the structure of code so reading the errors, I am unsure how to correct for them. It would be awesome if someone could help me understand how to specifically correct these error by providing a corrected code :)

Comment: Here is the corrected code after being placed in validator. Even though, this is not how the html will be placed inside my eliminator container on my website...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <title>Nav Control</title>
   </head>
<input class="lytbox-nav_control" id="nav-control" type="checkbox">
<div class="hamburguer">
<label class="lytbox-button" for="nav-control">
    <span>
    </span>
    <span>
    </span>
    <span>
    </span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="lytbox-navigation">
  [elementor-template id="1434"]
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Lighthouse is finding the `label` for `input#nav-control`, but there's no text within the `label`, which is causing the error.

If you don't want to put text inside of the `label`, try adding `aria-label` attribute to the `label` element. If that doesn't work, then use [`screen-reader-text` class](https://make.wordpress.org/accessibility/handbook/markup/the-css-class-screen-reader-text/) to add text that isn't visible.

```html
<input class="lytbox-nav_control" id="nav-control" type="checkbox">
<label class="lytbox-button" for="nav-control" aria-label="Toggle nav">
  <span class="screen-reader-text">Toggle nav</span>
  <div class="hamburguer">
    <span>
    </span>
    <span>
    </span>
    <span>
    </span>
  </div>
</label>
<div class="lytbox-navigation">
  [elementor-template id="1434"]
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the fast response! Could you be able to provide me an example of what the code would look like with the change or where I would specifically put that line of code?

Comment: Added code to my answer, with both `aria-label` and `screen-reader-text`; test each one separately and keep only one (having both is redundant).

Comment: Yes i saw the code, I am just unsure exactly where to place it. Instead of <label class="lytbox-button" for="nav-control" aria-label="Toggle nav"> it would be <aria-label class="lytbox-button" for="nav-control" aria-label="Toggle nav"> with a closing </aria-label> at the end?

Comment: No, what I've put in my answer is the correct implementation.

Comment: right but where do i put "aria-label" and or "screen-reader-text" specifically in the code? I don't know how to add an attribute.

Comment: The code in my answer shows where to put the `aria-label` attribute and `.screen-reader-text` elements.

Comment: Thanks Caleb! I was just briefly looking over this page, and for some reason was thinking the code was just still part of my response/question. I didn't realize you rewrote the code for me. (Brand new to stackoverflow) Thanks so much! This fixed my issue. I really appreciate your time and patience.